# CSS: Vertically centering line

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically center a horizontal line on the website. Example: the yellow line in the image below:

[image]

I've tried the following code so far.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-  left:-50%;top:50%;margin-top:-1px;width:100%;height:2px;">
<div style="height:2px;border:none;color:#ffff00;background-color:#ffff00;"></div></div></div>
```

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/1kxw9g9o/

As well as this, but it still doesn't work.

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
<div style="width:100%;height:2px;">
<div style="height:2px;border:none;color:#ffff00;background-color:#ffff00;"></div></div></div>
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/ttkwxdnh/

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. They work great, however I cannot get it to work the same way when I'm adding it to my website. After I paste the code the headline, and the text below it disappears, only showing the line. What am I missing? **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/8a3vwkcp

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [http://howtocenterincss.com/](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Comment: Your second jsFiddle works.  You just need to increase the height of the parent so that the effect is visible. https://jsfiddle.net/ttkwxdnh/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `height:100%` of your body, Html and parent div then it will be work

```css
html,
body{height:100%}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;height:100%">
<div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-50%;top:50%;margin-top:-1px;width:100%;height:2px;">
<div style="height:2px;border:none;color:#ffff00;background-color:#ffff00;"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great in this example, however I cannot get it to work the same way when I'm adding it to my website. After I paste the code the headline, and the text below it disappears, only showing the line. DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/8a3vwkcp/

Answer (score 2):

In order to vertically center the horizontal `div use absolute position alongside transform.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { position: relative; }
.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 2px /* whatever you want here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are looking for.

```css
.demo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <hr>
</div>
```